# Cannot play a video made with my Galaxy S3 camera

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, video

I took a video with my S3. After playing the video 3-5 times, this message appeared: `Cannot play video...sorry this video cannot be played...`

Why is this? I have MX Player.